# mock a shell script in Django/DRF test

Tags: python, django, shell

I tried to make some test on a method in views, but this method call a script shell, this script is write to work in another OS so I need to mocke this.

here the test:

```
@patch('check_web_share_file_folder.get_path_from_inode')
def test_list_with_search_mocked(self, mock_get_attribute):
    mock_get_attribute.return_value = 'expected value'
    request = self.factory.get('/fake-url')
    force_authenticate(request, user=self.user)

    view = WebShareFileFolderViewSet.as_view({'get': 'list'})
    response = view(request)

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

here the problem, I encounter this error with the test:

```
AttributeError: <function check_web_share_file_folder at 0x00000237FD567708> does not have the attribute 'get_path_from_inode'
```

check_web_share_file_folder.py have of course get_path_from_inode()

```
def get_path_from_inode(inode):
    std, err, code = popen_wrapper([
        'sudo', 'get_path_from_inode.sh',
        str(inode)
    ])
    if code != 0:
        return False
    return str(std.strip())[1:]
```

```
django/
├── webshare/
│   ├── actions
│   │      └── check_web_share_file_folder.py
│   ├────────
│   └── tests
│           └── factories
│                    └── test_web_share_file_folder_view.py
```

Comment: `check_web_share_file_folder` seems to be a function itself?

Comment: check_web_share_file_folder is a python file `check_web_share_file_folder.py`

but in the file there three function
`check_web_share_file_folder; get_path_from_inode; get_webshare_extattr`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure they files are in the same folder?

Also it seems like python tries to get 'get_path_from_inode' from *function*, not module 'check_web_share_file_folder.py'

UPD: Given your folder structure, you should change this part:
`@patch('webshare.actions.check_web_share_file_folder.get_path_from_inode')`

This is from dosc:
`@patch('package.module.ClassName.attribute', sentinel.attribute)`

https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock-examples.html

Comment: Its the same folder:
django/
├── webshare/
│   ├── actions
│   │      └── check_web_share_file_folder.py
│   ├────────
│   └── tests
│           └── factories
│                    └── test_web_share_file_folder_view.py

Comment: I edit the post with the same comments ;)

Comment: Given your folder structure, you should change this part: 
`@patch('webshare.actions.check_web_share_file_folder.get_path_from_inode')`

Comment: even with ```@patch('webshare.actions.check_web_share_file_folder.get_path_from_inode')``` I have the same problem, the project structure is on the initial post, the point is the path given to get_path_from_inode, the path shell is for the side server and is not used by the project himslef (on local is impossible)